# SQL statement with having, min , max

Tags: sql, group-by, count, pivot, window-functions

I have a table:

```
 ID                INTEGER NOT NULL,  -- AUTOMATIC RECORD'S ID
 CUSTOMER_ID       INTEGER NOT NULL,
 BILING_PERIOD     DATE    NOT NULL,
 DOCUMENT_ID       INTEGER NOT NULL,   
 DATE_CREATED      DATE    NOT NULL  -- WHEN THE DOCUMENT WAS CREATED
```

I want to select number of documents for customer in biling period,
id for the document that was created first in biling period for customer
and id for the document that was created last in biling period for customer.
All should be sorted by customer and biling period.
I want only biling periods that have more than 1 document for customer.

So when we have for example such data:

```
ID CUSTOMER_ID BILING_PERIOD DOCUMENT_ID DATE_CREATED
1  5           2020-01-01    123         2020-02-01
2  5           2020-01-01    22          2019-02-01
3  5           2020-01-01    3           2010-02-01
4  99          2020-01-01    458         2021-02-01
5  99          2020-01-01    64          2010-02-01
6  100         2020-01-01    120         2020-02-01
7  99          2019-06-01    452         2019-06-01
8  99          2019-06-01    546         2019-12-01
```

I want my results looks like that:

```
CUSTOMER_ID BILING_PERIOD NR_OF_DOC FIRST_DOC_ID LAST_DOC_ID
5           2020-01-01    3         3            123
99          2019-06-01    2         452          546
99          2020-01-01    2         64           458
```

Myself I can only count number of documents per user and period

```
SELECT customer_id, biling_period, count(*) as nr_of_doc
FROM T1
GROUP BY customer_id, biling_period
HAVING COUNT() > 1;

CUSTOMER_ID BILING_PERIOD NR_OF_DOC 
5           2020-01-01    3         
99          2019-06-01    2         
99          2020-01-01    2
```

I do not know hot to get document_id for newest and oldest document.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select 
    customer_id,
    billing_period,
    count(*),
    max(case when rn_asc  = 1 then document_id end) fist_doc_id,
    max(case when rn_desc = 1 then document_id end) last_doc_id
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over( 
            partition by customer_id, billing_period order by date_created
        ) rn_asc,
        row_number() over( 
            partition by customer_id, billing_period order by date_created desc
        ) rn_desc
    from t1 t
) t
group by customer_id, billing_period
having count(*) > 1
order by customer_id, billing_period
```

This will wodk properly even if the document ids are not in sequence.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ec1e4976dc656faac68e23f83776d100)**:

```
customer_id | billing_period | count | fist_doc_id | last_doc_id
----------: | :------------- | ----: | ----------: | ----------:
          5 | 2020-01-01     |     3 |           3 |         123
         99 | 2019-06-01     |     2 |         452 |         546
         99 | 2020-01-01     |     2 |          64 |         458
```

Comment: Great solution that takes into account that the `customer_id` field may have gaps. I was doing myself something like this a hundreth times, but this answer seems to be the cleanest answer that I saw so far.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample data, the document ids seem to be assigned in order.  If that is the case, you can just use aggregation:

```
SELECT customer_id, billing_period, count(*) as nr_of_doc,
       MIN(document_id), MAX(document_id)
FROM T1
GROUP BY customer_id, billing_period
HAVING COUNT() > 1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case